# Determining an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

I have a function $$f(\lambda)=n\ln(1-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})-\lambda p$$

I need to prove that $$f(\lambda)\leq \frac{\lambda^2}{8n}$$ using Taylor expansion.

I have used the taylor expansion for a function of the form $\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\dots$

Therefore: $f(\lambda)=n\ln[1-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}]-\lambda p=n[-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}+(p-p^2)e^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}+\frac{1}{2}e^{{2\lambda}{n}}-\dots]-\lambda p$

Not sure how to go on from here.

Comment: Taylor series are a good idea. Think of the $\ln$ as $\ln(1+x)$ where $x=p(e^{\lambda/n}-1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well I get factored out squares of p but I don't really know where to go from here

Comment: what restrictions are there on $p$ or $\lambda$, at least to make sure $ln$ is defined?

Comment: @snarfblaat $p \in (0,1)$ since it's a probability and $\lambda>0$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(\lambda) = \frac{pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}}{1-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}}$$

$$f''(\lambda) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}(1-p)pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}}{(1-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})^2}$$

$$f'''(\lambda) = \frac{1}{n}(1-p)p \frac{\frac{1}{n}e^{\frac{\lambda}{n}}(1-p -pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})}{(1-p+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})^3}$$

Use GM-AM inequality,
$$ f''(\lambda) \le \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4n}$$

Then $$ f(\lambda) = f(0) + f'(0)\lambda +\frac{1}{2}f''(\eta)(\lambda)^2  - p\lambda$$

$$\le \frac{1}{2}f''(\eta)(\lambda)^2 = \frac {\lambda^2}{8n}$$

Here $0 \le \eta \le \lambda$.

QED

Comment: another way is: $g(x)=f(x)-\dfrac{x^2}{8n}, g'=f'(x)-\dfrac{x}{4n}, g"=f"-\dfrac{1}{4n}, g"\le 0 \to g'\le 0 \to g \le 0$